# Use combining characters in concealment character

Tags: syntax-highlighting, conceal

Are combining characters allowed in a concealment character? The following does not seem to work:

```
syntax match underdot "a\." conceal cchar=ạ
```

The underdot is [`U+0323`](https://unicode-table.com/en/0323/). This syntax conceals `a.` simply as `a` rather than `ạ`. Is there something I can do to make this work, or is this a limitation of Vim?

Comment: Did you try using ạ instead?

Comment: @Mass That works, but I'm not specifically interested in that character, that was just one example.